# Python Regex: match any repeated words that are separated by exactly one other word

Tags: python, regex

I encountered this problem where I need to use regex to find repeated words separated by another word.

So if:

`"all in all"` will return: `"all"`

`"good good good"` will return: `Null` (Same word not another word)

I have tried:

```
p = re.compile(r'(\b\w+\b)\s\w+\s\1')
m = p.findall('all in all day in and day out bit by bit good good good')

print(m)
```

This returns `['all', 'bit', 'good']`, but I only want it to return `['all','bit']`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: adding negative lookahead should solve it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just need to add a negative lookahead for the word immediately following the initial capture group to ensure your regex can't match (for example) `good good`:

```
import re

p = re.compile(r'(\b\w+\b)(?!\s\1\b)\s\w+\s\1\b')
m = p.findall('all in all day in and day out bit by bit good good good')

print(m)
```

Output:

```
['all', 'bit']
```

If you want to include overlapping matches, make the entire regex a positive lookahead (thanks @ggorlen):

```
p = re.compile(r'(?=(\b\w+\b)(?!\s\1\b)\s\w+\s\1\b)')
m = p.findall('foo bar foo bar foo')
```

Output:

```
['foo', 'bar', 'foo']
```

If you also need to remove duplicate matches, convert to a `set` and back to a `list`:

```
p = re.compile(r'(?=(\b\w+\b)(?!\s\1\b)\s\w+\s\1\b)')
m = list(set(p.findall('foo bar foo bar foo')))
print(m)
```

Output:

```
['foo', 'bar']
```

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply! Exactly what I needed:)

Comment: On the input string `"foo bar foo bar foo"`, this regex gives `['foo']` but you might expect `['foo', 'bar', 'foo']`. Great answer nonetheless but worth noting. You can use `r'(?=(\b\w+\b)(?!\s\1\b)\s\w+\s\1)'` to make the matching overlap but performance should be awful with all the backtracking.

Comment: @code_aline ggorlen raises a good point - what do you want to do in that situation?

Comment: Thanks ggorlen and Nick! In that situation, I should be expecting only ['foo', 'bar'] in output. (no repeats of the same word)

Comment: @ggorlen good point - I will clarify with OP what their desired result is for that situation.

Comment: @code_aline you can convert to a set and back to a list to eliminate duplicates i.e. `m = list(set(m))`

Comment: @ggorlen regex101 seems to suggest that using a positive lookahead increases steps by ~70% which isn't too bad... anyway thanks for the comment and I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 3):

No need for regex; normal programming constructs can handle this sort of problem just fine. Write a loop and add a conditional:

```
s = 'all in all day in and day out bit by bit good good good'

words = s.split()
result = []

for i in range(len(words) - 2):
    if words[i] == words[i+2] and words[i] != words[i+1]:
        result.append(words[i])

print(result) # ['all', 'bit']
```

Comment: Or perhaps `result = [words[i] for i in range(len(words)-2) if words[i+1] != words[i] and words[i+2] == words[i]]`

Comment: Yep, that works too but I think the list comp is a little overburdened in this situation for my taste.

Comment: Thanks! It's good too but was trying to practise regex, so was trying to find a regex solution.